# 3.5/3.81 pitch connectors

Tags: connector

I've got a device that the manufacturer claims uses a 3.81mm pitch connector.  I measured the actual distance between pins, and it appears to be 3.5.  I'm now noticing that some connector manufacturers refer to a "3.5/3.81" connector.  I obviously don't want to buy the wrong one.  If a connector is listed as "3.81mm pitch", is that the same as a 3.5/3.81mm connector?  If it matters, I need [these connectors](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=1849-1057-ND) for an NI-USB-6001 DAQ

Comment: No that doesn't matter but what does, in order to make sense of your question, is a link to the datasheet of the connector that was supposedly 3.81 mm but wasn't. You also need to link to one that is referred to as "3.5/3.81".

Comment: For clarification: The pitch is the distance between the middle of the first pin to the middle of the second pin and not just the distance between the pins. Where exactly are you measuring from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.5 is obviously not the same as 3.81, and anything with more than about 2 pins is not going to fit, even if you force it on. Some manufacturers make series which are similar in size (eg. 5mm/5.08mm pitch) and combine the two in their literature because the construction is very similar between the two. When you drill down to the part numbers, they will be different for the two pitches.

I happen have a NI 6216 (different model but the same series) in front of me and the pitch is definitely 3.81mm (0.15") for the 16 pins/15 spaces. It also has mounting ears with captive screws and customized markings.

If you buy NI's terminal blocks you get whatever customization they do, the correct part, and a nifty screwdriver. For a price.

Comment: Thank you.  It's good to know that it's 3.81 (which is easier for me to find).  We are not using NI's custom connectors because our only vendor option is charging $55 for it and we specifically need spring connectors, not screw connectors

Answer (score 2):

3.81 mm = 0.150 " (American old school)
3.00 mm is preferred

Both types may be found in same category style of screw terminal power strips.  *Perhaps you are looking at the wrong datasheet.*  They may look the same in a photo.  [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

similar-looking pluggable connectors are available in both 3.5 and 3.81, be sure you choose the right pitch.

Choosing the right manufacturer is less of an issue. parts from different manufacurrers all seem to be interchangable (so long as you don'r exceed the manufacturers ratings)

[image: example]

this photo taken from a vendor who sells both 3.81 and 3.5mm pitch connectors